# using php mysqli create ledger book and get balance as per DR and CR

Tags: php, mysql

I have created a PHP ledger book system in the admin area to manage clients accounts amount.

I have created the below table in phpmyadmin:

[image]

I have tried using the below code for getting the result:

```
$list_balance = mysqli_query($con_db,"SELECT * FROM tbl_balancesheet where client_id='".$_GET['cid']."' ORDER by id desc" );
$total = 0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($list_balance)){
if($row['action_type']=='dr'){
    $debit = $row['amount'];
    $total += $row['amount'];
}else{
    $credit = $row['amount'];
    $total -= $row['amount']; 
}
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $row['created_date']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['particular']; ?></td>
    <td>
    <?php 
        if($row['action_type']=='dr'){ 
            echo $debit;
        }else{
            echo ' ';       
        }
    ?>
    </td>
    <td>
    <?php 
        if($row['action_type']=='cr'){ 
            echo $credit;
        }else{
            echo ' ';       
        }
    ?>
    </td>
    <td><?php echo $total; ?></td>
</tr>
```

I am getting the below result, but I don't want to show a minus (-) icon in front of balance:

[image]

Also, I want to display the last entry in first but the result is not displaying correctly.

The expected result should be as shown below

[image]
Please help me how I can get the above result. Also, how I can display the dr and cr.

**Ex:** If the admin asks money from customers **400** only. But some times customers had paid an advance amount to admin then the customer borrow money from admin. In that case, some times admin amount dr form customers and some times customers dr from admin.

Thanks

Comment: What output are you getting now? What is the question?

Comment: @nik, let me add output snapshot in question.

Comment: Regardless of order, regardless of `-`, I think the real question should be: how is "balance" column showing "400" on the first row of actual result? `$total` should be 700 on that first row. Not all code is shown (for instance: where's the closing `}` of the while?), so perhaps the mystery lies in the unposted.

Answer (score 2):

> I don't want to show a minus (-) icon in front of balance:

You should use [abs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.abs.php) function:

```
<td><?php echo abs($total); ?></td>
```

> Also, I want to display the last entry in first but the result is not displaying correctly.

In the code, in the sql query you have `ORDER by id desc` which means *descending* order by id (last inserted entry goes first)
If you want to change the order to *ascending* then remove `desc` from the query.

Comment: After the change, the `ORDER by id ASC`, don't need to add `abs` function. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: how I can get DR and CR in the balance column? Could you please help me out.

Comment: What exactly do you mean get? Could you provide an example? To display you need to `echo` the value you need in the corresponding cell.

Comment: I have posted one more question here [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55546877/using-php-mysqli-how-to-get-only-debtors-and-only-creditors-managed-with-action#55546877]. you can check with the example. I want to get only Debtors and Creditors in separate reports. Thanks