# Using PHP MYSQLi how to get only debtors and only creditors managed with action_type DR and CR

Tags: php, mysql

I have created the balance sheet system using PHP MYSQLi. Where admin can manage clients account information. Now I want to get only **DEBTORS** and only **CREDITORS**. I am managing both entries using `action_type` field 'dr' or 'cr'.

Below is the table structure:

[image: Table structure]

I have tried the below query for getting only DEBTORS:

```
SELECT *, client_id
     , SUM(COALESCE(CASE WHEN action_type = 'dr' THEN amount END,0)) total_debits
     , SUM(COALESCE(CASE WHEN action_type = 'cr' THEN amount END,0)) total_credits
     , SUM(COALESCE(CASE WHEN action_type = 'cr' THEN amount END,0)) - SUM(COALESCE(CASE WHEN action_type = 'dr' THEN amount END,0)) total_debtors
     , SUM(COALESCE(CASE WHEN action_type = 'dr' THEN amount END,0)) - SUM(COALESCE(CASE WHEN action_type = 'cr' THEN amount END,0)) balance 
  FROM tbl_balancesheet 
 GROUP  
    BY client_id
HAVING balance <> 0
```

But it's getting all results with DEBTORS and CREDITORS.

How I can get only DEBTORS and CREDITORS using the query or through PHP code?

Also, how I can display dr and cr in the balance column?

Please help!!!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you simply need to modify your `HAVING` clause, to filter out cases where `balance` is either more than zero (Debtor) OR `balance` is less than zero (Creditor).

You can also using conditional `IF()` expressions to determine **dr/cr** in the `balance` column.

To get **Debtors** only:

```
SELECT client_id, 
       Sum(Coalesce(CASE 
                      WHEN action_type = 'dr' THEN amount 
                    end, 0)) AS total_debits, 
       Sum(Coalesce(CASE 
                      WHEN action_type = 'cr' THEN amount 
                    end, 0)) AS total_credits, 
       Sum(Coalesce(CASE 
                      WHEN action_type = 'cr' THEN amount 
                    end, 0)) - Sum(Coalesce(CASE 
                                              WHEN action_type = 'dr' THEN 
                                              amount 
                                            end, 0)) AS total_debtors, 
       IF(Sum(Coalesce(CASE 
                         WHEN action_type = 'cr' THEN amount 
                       end, 0)) - Sum(Coalesce(CASE 
                                                 WHEN action_type = 'dr' THEN 
                                                 amount 
                                               end, 0)) > 0, 'dr', 'cr') AS balance 
FROM   tbl_balancesheet 
GROUP  BY client_id 
HAVING balance = 'dr' AND total_debtors <> 0
```

---

To get **Creditors** only:

```
SELECT client_id, 
       Sum(Coalesce(CASE 
                      WHEN action_type = 'dr' THEN amount 
                    end, 0)) AS total_debits, 
       Sum(Coalesce(CASE 
                      WHEN action_type = 'cr' THEN amount 
                    end, 0)) AS total_credits, 
       Sum(Coalesce(CASE 
                      WHEN action_type = 'cr' THEN amount 
                    end, 0)) - Sum(Coalesce(CASE 
                                              WHEN action_type = 'dr' THEN 
                                              amount 
                                            end, 0)) AS total_debtors, 
       IF(Sum(Coalesce(CASE 
                         WHEN action_type = 'cr' THEN amount 
                       end, 0)) - Sum(Coalesce(CASE 
                                                 WHEN action_type = 'dr' THEN 
                                                 amount 
                                               end, 0)) > 0, 'dr', 'cr') AS balance 
FROM   tbl_balancesheet 
GROUP  BY client_id 
HAVING balance = 'cr' AND total_debtors <> 0
```

Comment: Thanks for your answers, it's working what I want. If the debtors and creditors balance is 0 or `null` than they not in the list. Like if debtors are given complete payment to admin then he will not in the list.

Comment: @mageDev0688 If balance is zero. It will show up in creditor list. It is not a debtor I believe.

Comment: I mean, if the customer pays to admin with the complete amount, then he will not list in the debtor. Because customer payment is clear.

Comment: @mageDev0688 yeah so my query is doing the same. If balance is zero. It does not show up in debtor list.

Comment: Please see this snapshot for more clear [http://prntscr.com/n9kaij]. This customer balance is 0. But it's still in debtors list. [http://prntscr.com/n9kbbx]

Comment: Thanks, it's working, but now how I can do the same for creditors if the payment is clear then the client will not list in the creditors as well.

Comment: Many thanks, Madhur Bhaiya. Thanks a lot, one thing just let you know. I'm also from Jaipur.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191535/discussion-between-madhur-bhaiya-and-magedev0688).

Comment: I have added one more question here [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55495976/using-php-mysqli-create-ledger-book-and-get-balance-as-per-dr-and-cr]. I have done up calculation related thing, but not getting `dr` and `cr`.

Comment: here I have an issue with the result. Could you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question right, you need a simple WHERE statement. So, your query should be something like this:

```
SELECT *, client_id
     , SUM(COALESCE(CASE WHEN action_type = 'dr' THEN amount END,0)) total_debits
     , SUM(COALESCE(CASE WHEN action_type = 'cr' THEN amount END,0)) total_credits
     , SUM(COALESCE(CASE WHEN action_type = 'cr' THEN amount END,0)) - SUM(COALESCE(CASE WHEN action_type = 'dr' THEN amount END,0)) total_debtors
     , SUM(COALESCE(CASE WHEN action_type = 'dr' THEN amount END,0)) - SUM(COALESCE(CASE WHEN action_type = 'cr' THEN amount END,0)) balance 
  FROM tbl_balancesheet 
  WHERE `action_type` = 'cr'
 GROUP  
    BY client_id
HAVING balance <> 0
```

Or, not using the action_type column, but instead using the calculated columns:

```
SELECT *, client_id
     , SUM(COALESCE(CASE WHEN action_type = 'dr' THEN amount END,0)) total_debits
     , SUM(COALESCE(CASE WHEN action_type = 'cr' THEN amount END,0)) total_credits
     , SUM(COALESCE(CASE WHEN action_type = 'cr' THEN amount END,0)) - SUM(COALESCE(CASE WHEN action_type = 'dr' THEN amount END,0)) total_debtors
     , SUM(COALESCE(CASE WHEN action_type = 'dr' THEN amount END,0)) - SUM(COALESCE(CASE WHEN action_type = 'cr' THEN amount END,0)) balance 
  FROM tbl_balancesheet 
  WHERE `action_type` = 'cr'
 GROUP  
    BY client_id
HAVING balance <> 0 AND total_credits > 0
```

The second query will return everyone who has credits (hence is creditor). Does that work?

Comment: No, this query statement I already know, but if I use this query It'll return all the ``action_type` = 'cr'` rows only. I want to get if anyone is the credit to me than I want those lists only who credit me.

Comment: Can you provide an example on what you need? Also, check out the edit @mageDev0688

Comment: Yes sure, let me explain. I have lots of customers and suppliers. Some customers bring some goods from me on credit and they will return payment to me later, so they are my debtors. And some times suppliers send me raw materials to me on credit for sort time, so they are my creditors. Now I want to get only Detors and only Creditors from single table.

Comment: Does that second query make more sense?

Comment: Let me check with the second query.

Comment: Well, unless you can provide example output that you need, I dont think anyone can help you. Both queries return only what you define as "creditors", so you will have to show as an example output that you need, and explain what exactly is not working for you.